# PySide DLL loading conflict within a C++ / Qt application

Tags: c++, python, qt, dll, pyside

I have a C++ application which uses the Core, GUI and Network modules of Qt 4.x. It calls python callbacks when the user does certain actions, the point being that the user can customize these callbacks by writing python code.

When I try to import the QtNetwork module from PySide within a callback like this :

```
from PySide import QtNetwork
```

I get the following **error** :

`dll load failed : the specified procedure could not be found`

Note that I don't get the error when I import the QtCore and QtGui modules.

I used **dependency walker** to try to figure out the issue.
When the application starts, it loads `QtCore4.dll`, `QtGui4.dll` and `QtNetwork4.dll` which are the **C++ Qt DLLs** placed in my application's directory.
When I trigger a callback to my python code that imports QtNetwork from PySide, it loads `QtNetwork.pyd` and then gives me the error :

`LoadLibraryExA("C:\Dev\Python27\lib\site-packages\PySide\QtNetwork.pyd", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: the specified procedure could not be found (127).`

My dependency tree of `QtNetwork.pyd` :
[image: dependency tree of QtNetwork.pyd]
seems to indicate that **it uses the already loaded C++ DLLs** instead of the PySide ones. I guess that is because their name are identical.
Is there a way to make it load the right DLLs (the ones in the `c:\dev\python27\lib\site_package\pyside\` directory )?
Also, why doesn't this conflict matters with QtCore and QtGui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if your `QTNETWORK4.DLL` satisfy requirements:

- is for your architecture
- have the same version as your Qt libs, using witch you compile your program
- is compiled by the same compiler

Best way is just copy libs you need from Qt's `bin` directory to your build directory.

So, I think this **conflict matters only with `QTNETWORK4.DLL`** because this lib has some other version (don't satisfy requirements above).

**The way to make it load right DLLs** is to add to your `path` environment variable path to your Qt's `bin` directory, and delete DLLs from your programs directory -- so, it can find needed libs from `path`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am pretty sure that the version of the network DLL is not the issue here. I only have one Qt version installed and compiled. Plus, the DLL I use is already the one from the `bin` directory.
The real issue I believe is that the `.PYD` should load the DLL from the PySide directory `c:\dev\python27\...\pyside` and not the one from the application directory nor the one from the `bin` folder of my Qt directory.
Even with the PySide directory in my `path` environment variable, the PySide DLL will not be loaded by the `.PYD`

Comment: Just try to delete `QTNETWORK4.DLL` from your project dir and place your `c:\dev\python27\...\pyside` before `C:\Qt\bin` dir in your `path`

Comment: If my PySide directory is placed before my `Qt\bin` directory in the `path`, when the application starts, it will try to load the Python DLLs instead of the C++ ones and will exit with an entry point error.

Comment: Well, my bad, you were right. It was a version compatibility issue. PySide is linked against Qt 4.8.2 and I was using 4.8.3 for the compilation. I didn't know this could make such a difference.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: That's nice, best regards, have a nice holidays! :)